# Copy a data from a file into a structure

Tags: matlab, struct

I need help in designing a data structure to store the storm data from the file. I am going to use these field names: code, amount, duration, and intensity. The intensity is the rainfall amount divided by the duration.(what should I do to in order to calculate the intensity?) I loaded the data into the variable "mydata", then copied my data into a vector of structs called "vecdata".

My final vector of structures should have the same number of elements as the number of rows in the data file. Additionally, it should have the 4 fields with the field names I mentioned above.

```
% Creating an example data file 
anum = randi([3,10]);
thedata = [randi([1,350],anum,1),rand(anum,1)*5,rand(anum,1)*15];
save mydata.dat thedata -ascii
clear

%  loaded the data using the load function into "mydata":
mydata = load('mydata.dat') 

% Tried to copy the data from "mydata" into a vector of structures called "vecdata":

vecdata = [struct('code','amount','duration','intensity')];
```

This is a very general question. How can I copy the data from the file above? Rows of mydata must match the # of elements in vecdata. How do I check this?

Comment: Please clean up the code, it contains every line twice. How should the struct look like? Your data has three columns but your struct has four fields? Or do you want an empty struct of that `anum` with the fieldnames?

Comment: The intensity field is amount divided by duration, the struct should have appropriate values there.

Comment: Your code still contained some duplicated lines and `'`. For future questions, simply indent your full code with one tab and it will be displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
%first of all, calculate the missing intensity
mydata(:,end+1)=mydata(:,3)./mydata(:,2);
%define the fieldnames for your struct
labels={'code','amount','duration','intensity'};
%there is no array2struct, so we convert to cell first and use cell2struct.
cell2struct(num2cell(mydata),labels,2)
```